# How to prevent direct2d “stretching” the view when window size changed?

Tags: c++, mfc, directx, sharpdx, direct2d

I am rendering text with `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`.

When there is a change of the UI window size, I want to prevent the stretch of the text being rendered - so it will be unchanged until I will directly make a rendering command.

On [Direct2D documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1hwndrendertarget) the behavior is described:

> If EndDraw presents the buffer, this bitmap is stretched to cover the
>   surface where it is presented: the entire client area of the window

I know the [ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1hwndrendertarget) method but I don't want to update the size immediately, just going to use it later on according to my program needs.

**How can I ignore windows events to prevent this visual stretch?**

Answer (score 0):

You are already ignoring size change messages, and that's why surface size does not match client area size when presenting. You can try to offset this effect by setting target resolution according to "client area / current target size" factor, right before doing EndDraw(). I have no idea if that will help, or what will happen to uncovered window area outside of current target rectangle.